# How do you create a diffFunction in Java for use in QNMinimizer?

Tags: java, function, stanford-nlp, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use QNMinimizer from the Stanford NLP library and am having trouble with the parameters I need to make qn.minimize run properly.

```
QNMinimzer qn = new QNMinimizer(10, true)
qn.minimize(null, 1e-5, new double[] {0,0,0}, 400)
```

I need to put an object of type diffFunction where the "null" is but am not sure how to create/implement one. I have a method that uses gradient descent and want to incorporate that into the diffFunction object.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to implement the `DiffFunction` interface -- Really I'd recommend [`AbstractCachingDiffFunction`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/optimization/AbstractCachingDiffFunction.java) once you understand what's going on, just because it's more efficient and comes with some nice utility functions (e.g., a gradient checker).

At a high level, for any input vector [image: x \in R^k] (represented as a double vector of length k), you need to provide two values: the value of your function [image: y = f_{\theta}(x) \in R], and a gradient [image: \frac{d}{d\theta}f_\theta(x) \in R^k], output as a double vector of length [image: k].

The dimension `k` is defined in [`Function#domainDimension`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/optimization/Function.java#L24) (a supeinterface of `DiffFunction`).

The value `y` is defined in [`Function#valueAt`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/optimization/Function.java#L17).

The gradient is defined in [`DiffFunction#derivativeAt`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/optimization/DiffFunction.java#L20).

If you have gradient descent already implemented, the value `y` will be the value of the loss. The gradient will be the gradient in gradient descent. If you have stochastic gradient descent rather than batch gradient descent. the value `y` is the sum of the losses over your dataset, and same with the gradient.